# Sleep Processes are Running Longer Than Allowed

Tags: mysql, performance, sleep

From time to time my mysql server will run into a "too many connections" error.  I believe part of the problem is large amount of `sleep` processes that are running, some over 1000 seconds.

When looking into the issue, I saw [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/1558/2712) and investigated.  I checked my timeout values with

```
show variables like "%timeout";
```

And both `interactive_timeout` and `wait_timeout` are set to `600`.

How/Why would these sleep processes be running so long, if they're supposed to stop at 600?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities the come to mind:

- the values of `interactive_timeout` and `wait_timeout` were not 600 when those threads first connected, so they are using the values that existed when they first connected, or
- the application is changing the timeout values for its sessions after connecting.

If you're running out of available connections, though, why not just raise `max_connections`?   If the threads are sleeping, you're not talking about a significant resource cost.